# Check if a row in one DataFrame exist in another, BASED ON SPECIFIC COLUMNS ONLY

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas DataFrame with different columns number.

df1 is a single row DataFrame:

```
       a   X0   b     Y0    c

0    233  100  56  shark  -23
```

df2, instead, is multiple rows Dataframe:

```
         d   X0   e   f     Y0   g    h

0     snow  201  32  36    cat  58  336
1     rain  176  99  15  tiger  63  845
2      sun  193  81  42    dog  48  557
3    storm  100  74  18  shark  39  673     # <-- This row
4    cloud  214  56  27   wolf  66  406
```

I would to verify if the df1's row is in df2, but considering X0 AND Y0 columns only, ignoring all other columns.
In this example the df1's row match the df2's row at index 3, that have 100 in X0 and 'shark' in Y0.

The output for this example is:

```
True
```

Note: True/False as output is enough for me, I don't care about index of matched row.

I founded similar questions but all of them check the entire row...

Comment: Please post your expected output. Where do you want `True` and `False` to appear?

Comment: If it's just one row, using `df.loc` with two conditions is definitely something you should consider. All the other methods proposed here can be pretty costly for large dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `duplicated`

```
df2.append(df1).duplicated(['X0', 'Y0']).iat[-1]

True
```

Save a tad bit of time

```
df2[['X0', 'Y0']].append(df1[['X0', 'Y0']]).duplicated().iat[-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with an `if` condition check on `len`:

```
In [219]: if len(df1[['X0', 'Y0']].merge(df2)):
     ...:     print(True)
     ...: 
True
```

**OR:**

```
In [225]: not (df1[['X0', 'Y0']].merge(df2)).empty
Out[225]: True
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this... however, you can use the `empty` attribute as well. `df1[['X0', 'Y0']].merge(df2).empty`

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks for that. Updated my answer.

Comment: you don't need the `if` statement. printing the condition alone suffices

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df2[(df2.X0.isin(df1.X0))&(df2.Y0.isin(df1.Y0))]
```

Output:

```
      d      X0      e   f   Y0     g    h
3   storm   100     74  18  shark   39  673
```